# Leaflet WMS from geoserver is not working

Tags: leaflet

I am using leaflet in order to create my project. The map I am using as tile layer is from openstreetmap. However, I want to add mapping from Geoserver. It is a shapefile that was added with the postgis CRS 4326. When open the browser does  not show anything.

```
var map = L.map('map', {
      crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326, 

}).setView([31.9252738952637, -26.8797512054443], 9);

var mywms = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/turismo/wms", {
    layers: 'turismo:bairros',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    version: '1.1.0',
    attribution: "myattribution"
});
mywms.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Can you use Fiddler to see what actual GetMap request is sent to GeoServer.  Does that same request work in a browser?.

Comment: Use the developer console in your browser, and see what URLs are being requested to the WMS server. Copy-paste such a URL in your question.